# How to create technical architecture document of iPhone mobile application

Tags: iphone

I have developed an applicaiton for client and now i need to create a technical architecture document, but i am strugling in how to start and what are the content i need to add in the document.

If any one have any sample then please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

here's a template SWAD document: [click](http://www.opfro.org/Components/WorkProducts/ArchitectureSet/SoftwareArchitectureDocument/SoftwareArchitectureDocumentStandard.doc)

use it as a starting point and go trough and document only the aspects that are required for your app or by the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Technical Architecture document should consist of:

- the technical problem you plan to solve with your application,
- a technical diagram of your application,
- an explanation how you plan to solve the problem.
- It should also mention non functional requirements, like have you considered scalability, security, performance, and why did you design your architecture this way.

You can conclude with assumptions you have made.